# Can you bound the third moment from the second moment?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, moments, bounds

Suppose $X$ is a random real variable with zero mean and finite second moment $\langle X^2\rangle$. Under what conditions can we give a bound (upper/lower) for the third moment $\langle X^3\rangle$?

Comment: What kinds of "conditions" do you have in mind?  You need *something,* because the third moment can be undefined (consider the Student $t$ distribution with 3 df, for instance), it can be infinite, and it can be negatively infinite: there are no general bounds.

Comment: That actually answers my question, thanks @whuber

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such universal bound.

**Here is a cute fact to put this question in perspective:**

> Given real numbers $k^\prime \gt k \ge 0,$ there exist random variables $X$ that have a finite $k^\text{th}$ moment but infinite $k^{\prime\,\text{th}}$ moment.

It doesn't matter whether we consider these raw moments or central moments: see [How to prove that the $r^\text{th}$ raw moment exists if and only if the $r^\text{th}$ central moment exists?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251431).

To prove the fact, let $X$ be supported on $[1,\infty)$ with a density proportional to $(1 + x^2)^{-(k^\prime+1) /2}.$  Since $k^\prime \gt 0,$ this density integrates to a finite number, showing such distributions exist.

Because $1+x^2 \gt x^2,$

$$\mu_{k}(X) \propto \int_1^\infty \frac{x^k\,\mathrm{d}x}{(1 + x^2)^{(k^\prime+1)/2}} \le \int_1^\infty x^{k - k^\prime - 1}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{k^\prime - k} \le \infty$$

but since $1+x^2 \le 2x^2,$

$$\mu_{k^\prime}(X) \propto \int_1^\infty \frac{x^{k^\prime}\,\mathrm{d}x}{(1 + x^2)^{(k^\prime+1)/2}} \gt \int_1^\infty \frac{x^{k^\prime}\,\mathrm{d}x}{(2 x^2)^{(k^\prime+1)/2}} \propto \int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\log(x)$$

diverges, *QED.*

The question concerns the case $k^\prime=3$ and $k=2.$  To apply the foregoing analysis, let $\sigma^k$ be the given $k^{\text{th}}$ moment and let $X$ be the random variable described above.  Then the $k^\text{th}$ moment of $$ \frac{\sigma\,X}{\mu_k(X)^{1/k}} $$ equals $\sigma^k$ but its $k^{\prime\,\text{th}}$ moment is infinite.

Comment: +1, whuber. I changed the linked post's title and hence this minor edit to your post.