# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^3 f(x) dx < \infty$ then $Cov(X,X)<\infty$ ? TRUE OR FALSE

Tags: self-study, inference, expected-value, integral

$x  \in  R$ is a continuous random variable.

Is the statement :  IF $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^3 f(x) dx < \infty$ then: $Cov(X,X)<\infty$ .TRUE?

My thought was that Var(x)=Cov(x,x) , so $Var(x)= E(x^2) - E^2(x)$.
Hence

both $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 f(x) dx < \infty$  and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx < \infty$

so I think the Question can be written as:

Is it true that IF $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^3 f(x) dx < \infty$ then both $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 f(x) dx < \infty$  and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx < \infty$?.

It looks False to me. But I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: IF $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 f(x) dx = infty$  does that mean that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx = \infty$?.

Comment: Hint: where does $|x|³>x²$ occur? Remark: the assumption should be $\int |x|^3 f(x)\,\text dx<\infty$

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244202 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251431 show several techniques to address this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that IF $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^3 f(x) dx < \infty$ then
> both $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 f(x) dx < \infty$  and
> $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx < \infty$?.
>
> It looks False to me. But I am not sure how to prove it.

Instead it sound me true. There is a theorem that warrant us that if moment of order $k$ exist then all lower order moments exists too. If third order moment exist, variance must exist.